# How to have the option of having a user add an image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application for the first time and I was wondering how can I have a option of having the user upload an image. Like for example, in a contact manager the user has the option of uploading an image of a contact. I was wondering how can I do that in my android application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what have you tried ..?? Or its just a concept yet

Comment: You can also select from ur sdcard and can show in the ImageView
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: In my app, I want to have a button, when the user clicks on it, they can then upload an image. I have tried searching online, but I can't find what I am looking for. So can someone tell me the method of adding a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from scratch..

1)Take a look at **INTENT**

**[Android Intent](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)**

Then  take a look at this blogpost

**[Image Upload](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/)**

Hope this helps you

Comment: accpt some answer... @user123456

Answer (score 0):

In this one you want to click the image view to get image from sd card.. If you want to change to button then replace the listener from image to button.

```
 int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
 image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

getting image from sd card:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
        && null != data) {

    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
}
}
```