# Pick Image from Gallery/Camera/DropBox etc

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera-intent

How to give user the option to choose image from `Camera`/`Gallery`/`DropBox` OR any other File systems from the device and show it in an activity as an `ImageView` object.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798883/how-to-have-the-option-of-having-a-user-add-an-image-in-android/18798938#18798938

Comment: But, it gets the image only from SD card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For picking image from Camera/Gallery/DropBox OR any other File systems from the device just call implicit intent...

Following code may helps you...

```
pickbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals("mounted")){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture:"), Constants.PICK_IMAGE_FROM_LIBRARY);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now use OnActivity result for getting data...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == Constants.PICK_IMAGE_FROM_LIBRARY)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            mImagePath = selectedImagePath;
            Bitmap photo = getPreview(selectedImagePath);
            mImageViewProfileImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
public String getPath(Uri uri)
{
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

public Bitmap getPreview(String fileName)
{
    File image = new File(fileName);

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);

    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight : bounds.outWidth;
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / 64;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show all the apps installed in the phone that can deal with photos such as Camera, Gallery, Dropbox, etc.

You can do something like:

1.- Ask for all the intents available:

```
    Intent camIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    Intent gallIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    gallIntent.setType("image/*"); 

    // look for available intents
    List<ResolveInfo> info=new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
    List<Intent> yourIntentsList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(camIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(camIntent);
        finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
        info.add(res);
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> listGall = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(gallIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGall) {
        final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(gallIntent);
        finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
        info.add(res);
    }
```

2.- Show a custom dialog with the list of items:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.select_an_action));
    dialog.setAdapter(buildAdapter(context, activitiesInfo),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = intents.get(id);
                    context.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                }
            });

    dialog.setNeutralButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.cancel),
            new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
```

This is a full example: https://gist.github.com/felixgborrego/7943560