# Intent to open dropbox for picking image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application after button click I want to show chooser of available photo applications in my app. The goal is to pick image from one of the photo-related apps and show it in my app.

After button click following method is being executed:

```
private void fireIntentToOpenDeviceImageResources() {
    Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");        

    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
    imageUri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent, takePicture});

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GlobalConsts.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

The problem is that I don't see dropbox app (it is for sure installed in my testing phone) in created chooser. What kind of intent I should add in order to include dropbox app?

**EDIT:**

I added such intent:

```
PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dropbox.android");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);       
getIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Now it shows dropbox app in chooser but I can't pick the image from it. It simply launches dropbox app without picking and returning to my app possibility.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870169/pick-image-from-gallery-camera-dropbox-etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces the [Storage Access Framework (SAF)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), with a centralized document access. You can open to the document chooser with this simple code:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
getIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(getIntent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

For this reason on Android >=19 your code will open the intent chooser with various app, for example `Camera`, `Photos` (etc, etc... depends on what apps are installed) and `Documents`. If you select `Documents` the document chooser will open and on the sidebar there are all the different apps installed in your device, including Dropbox.

If you want that Dropbox will be directly available in the intent chooser you can change your code like this:

```
private void fireIntentToOpenDeviceImageResources() {
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
    Uri imageUri = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    Intent dropboxIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    dropboxIntent.setPackage("com.dropbox.android");
    dropboxIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Select Image");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{takePicture, dropboxIntent});

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GlobalConsts.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

**Warning!** With this technique you need to manually add every app that it was available only in the document chooser, for example if you want to add also ES File Manager you need to create the intent and add to the list of `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`:

```
Intent esFileManagerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
esFileManagerIntent.setPackage("com.estrongs.android.pop");
esFileManagerIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Select Image");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{takePicture, dropboxIntent, esFileManagerIntent});
```

Comment: Great information. Your answer helped to solve my problem. Thanks!